# What is the consistency strength of weak Vopenka's principle?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

*Weak Vopěnka's principle* says that

> the opposite of the category of ordinals cannot be fully embedded in any locally presentable category.

Recall that one form of Vopěnka's principle says that the category of ordinals cannot be fully embedded in any locally presentable category.

Adámek and Rosický show that weak Vopěnka's principle follows from Vopěnka's principle and implies the existence of a proper class of measurables, giving a rough indication of its consistency strength. Its interest lies in its equivalence to the principle that any full subcategory of a locally presentable category closed under limits is reflective, or its equivalence to the principle that every orthogonal subcategory of a locally presentable category is reflective.

But these results date from Adámek and Rosický's 1994 book *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories*.

**Question:** Is a more precise understanding of weak Vopěnka's principle available today? In particular, is its consistency strength well-calibrated?

Comment: I am trying to recall this statement of VP (that ORD admits no full embedding in any locally presentable cat) and I can't find it.  Isn't ORD the skeleton of LinOrdSet, though?

Comment: @HarryGindi Not every linear order is a well-order.

Comment: @HarryGindi Not only is not every linear a well-order, but the morphisms of well-orderings are also much more restrictive than those of linear orders. For the statement, see Lemma 6.2 of Adamek-Rosicky. From a large discrete full subcategory $(A_i)_{i \in Ord} \subseteq C$, one constructs an embedding $Ord \to C$ by sending $i \mapsto \amalg_{j < i} A_j$. Conversely, an embedding $Ord \to C$ for $C$ locally presentable contradicts the form of Vopenka's principle which says that any class $(A_i)_{i \in Ord} \subseteq C$ admits a morphism $A_i \to A_j$ for some $i < j$.

Comment: The construction of an embedding $Ord \to C$ given above only works in certain $C$, such as the category of graphs, but that's fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The weak Vopěnka principle (WVP) and semi-weak Vopěnka principle (SWVP) are both equivalent to the large cardinal principle "Ord is Woodin".  These results now appear in a [paper on the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00284.pdf). I kept the proof that Ord is Woodin implies SWVP as part of this MathOverflow answer (see below), but removed the outline of the proof that WVP implies Ord is Woodin because the paper contains a better proof of that now.

I will use the form of WVP which says that the opposite of the category of ordinals cannot be fully embedded in the category of graphs.  In other words, there is no sequence of graphs $(G_\alpha : \alpha < \mathrm{Ord})$ such that for all $\alpha < \beta$ there is no homomorphism from $G_\alpha$ to $G_\beta$, and for all $\alpha \le \beta$ there is a unique homomorphism from $G_\beta$ to $G_\alpha$.

SWVP (see Adámek and Rosický, *On Injectivity in Locally Presentable Categories*) says that there is no sequence of graphs $(G_\alpha : \alpha < \mathrm{Ord})$ such that for all $\alpha < \beta$ there is no homomorphism from $G_\alpha$ to $G_\beta$, and for all $\alpha \le \beta$ there is at least one homomorphism from $G_\beta$ to $G_\alpha$.

For every similarity type consisting of finitary relation symbols, the category of all structures of this type can be fully embedded into the category of graphs (see Hedrlín and Pultr, *On full embeddings of categories of algebras*,) so replacing graphs by more general relational structures yields equivalent statements of WVP and SWVP.

"Ord is Woodin" means that for every class $A$ there is an $A$-strong cardinal.  See Kanamori, *The Higher Infinite* for the definition of $A$-strong cardinal. For maximum generality, we work in GB + AC.  (As a special case, the results hold in ZFC for definable classes $A$.)

**Proof that Ord is Woodin implies SWVP.**

Assume Ord is Woodin and let $(G_\alpha : \alpha \in \mathrm{Ord})$ be a sequence of graphs such that for all $\alpha \le \beta$ there is at least one homomorphism from $G_\beta$ to $G_\alpha$.  We will show that for some ordinal $\kappa$ there is a homomorphism from $G_\kappa$ to $G_{\kappa+1}$.

We can write $G_\alpha = G(\alpha)$ where $G$ is a class function with domain Ord.  Because Ord is Woodin, some cardinal $\kappa$ is $G$-strong. 
Take a cardinal $\beta$ greater than $\kappa$ and greater than the von Neumann rank of the graph $G(\kappa+1)$, meaning $G(\kappa+1) \in V_\beta$.  Because $\kappa$ is $\beta$-$G$-strong, there is a transitive class $M$ containing $V_\beta$ and an elementary embedding $j : (V;\in) \to (M;\in)$ such that the critical point of $j$ is $\kappa$ and $V_\beta \subset M$ and $j(\kappa) > \beta$ and $j(G) \restriction \beta = G \restriction \beta$.  We describe the latter condition by saying that $j$ *coheres with* $G$.

Because $j$ coheres with $G$, the graph $G(\kappa+1)$ is equal to $j(G)(\kappa+1)$, so it is on the sequence $j(G)$, which is an Ord-sequence of graphs in $M$. Note that $j(G(\kappa)) = j(G)(j(\kappa))$ by the elementarity of $j$, so the graph $j(G(\kappa))$ is also on the sequence $j(G)$. We have $j(\kappa) > \kappa+1$, so by our assumption on the sequence $G$ and the elementarity of $j$, we have a homomorphism $j(G(\kappa)) \to G(\kappa+1)$ in $M$ and therefore in $V$.  We also have a homomorphism $G(\kappa) \to j(G(\kappa))$ in $V$ given by $j \restriction G(\kappa)$.  Composing these, we obtain a homomorphism $G(\kappa) \to G(\kappa+1)$, as desired.

Comment: Now, when you say class, I'm guessing you mean definable, or are we talking about a hierarchy of strength here by stronger and stronger second-order systems?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much difference to the proof, so it's best to prove it for arbitrary classes in GBC.  Then we obtain the following consequences as special cases: (1) In ZFC, WVP for definable classes is equivalent to "Ord is definably Woodin", and (2) for every inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, WVP in $V_\kappa$ (for all classes that are elements of $V_{\kappa+1}$) is equivalent to "$\kappa$ is a Woodin cardinal."

Comment: Also, I think a refinement of the argument should prove that WVP for $\mathbf{\Pi}_1$ classes and WVP for $\mathbf{\Sigma}_2$ classes are both equivalent to the existence of a proper class of strong cardinals.  Perhaps one can obtain analogous results higher in the Levy hierarchy, like Bagaria did for VP.  I don't know what the higher definable analogs of strong cardinals are.

Comment: This is awesome! I hope you write it up in a paper!

Comment: @TimCampion  Thanks!  I hope to have time to do that soon.

Comment: Trevor, this is great! If my understanding is correct, the question has been open for some time and was of interest to many people.  You should write to Joan Bagaria to let him know that it has finally been answered.

Comment: @Victoria Thanks!  I will let him know.

Comment: Somehow when I first read this post, the formulation "ORD is Woodin" sounded a bit weird and technical to me. I'm only just now noticing the obvious fact that a "basically equivalent" way of saying this is that "A weak-Vopenka cardinal is precisely a Woodin cardinal". The intrusion of "ORD is" in the formulation is 100% parallel to the fact that Vopenka's principle basically says "ORD is a Vopenka cardinal". So from this perspective -- seeing that WVP is to Woodin cardinals as VP is to Vopenka cardinals -- it's clear that WVP is an extremely canonical point in the large cardinal hierarchy

Comment: I'm also just now appreciating that I actually like SWVP better than WVP -- it's related to the formulation of VP which says "For every ORD-indexed sequence of objects $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha<ORD}$, there is a morphisms $A_\alpha \to A_\beta$ for some $\alpha<\beta$" in the same way as WVP is related to the discrete-subcategory formulation of VP. I like the formulation leading to SWVP better because it doesn't require messing around with rigid objects or ensuring that various morphisms are _unique_ -- which ends up feeling kind of unnatural category-theoretically.

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, "Ord is Woodin" sounds a bit awkward.  Maybe this point in the large cardinal hierarchy will eventually be called just "WVP" with the equivalence to a large cardinal principle being understood implicitly, the same way "VP" is often used now in set theory to refer to any large cardinal principle equivalent to VP.  By the way, the analogy WVP : Woodin cardinals :: VP : Vopenka cardinals has an interesting hole in it, namely that the natural definition of "weak Vopenka cardinal" doesn't imply inaccessibility like any natural definition of "Vopenka cardinal" does...

Comment: ...so the inaccessible weak Vopenka cardinals are the Woodin cardinals, but there can also be smaller weak Vopenka cardinals.  In particular, if the Proper Forcing Axiom holds then $\aleph_2$ is a weak Vopenka cardinal -- I wonder whether there is any application of this fact to category theory.

Comment: Regarding SWVP versus WVP, there is another such principle that is equivalent to "Ord is Woodin", namely: for every Ord-length inverse limit system of graphs (or whatever) there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that for all ordinals $\beta > \alpha$ the canonical homomorphism from the inverse limit up to $\beta$ to the inverse limit up to $\alpha$ is a retraction.  Perhaps requiring the morphisms to commute is more natural than requiring them to be unique.

Answer (score 5):

The best that I can tell is in [these slides](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmtadb/AccessibleCategories2018/Bagaria.pdf). Joan Bagaria gave a beautiful talk at *Accessible Categories and their connections* in Leeds, this very July.

Comment: From the discussion in the slides, I take it that not much more is known definitively about this than 20 years ago, but that there are some interesting ideas about how to approach it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!